# ES6 de-structuring - what does this do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand this ES6 de-structuring. Can someone explain what this line of code will compile to?

```
const { loading, route: { pageName = 'default' } = {} } = this.props;
```

Comment: you are extracting `loading` from `this.props.loading` and extracting `pageName` from `this.props.route.pageName` in case there is no route it will be defaultet to an empty object `{}` if there is no `pageName` in `route` object it will be defaulted to "default", this line of code introduces 2 const variables, loading and pageName

Comment: I often find putting new code it into the online babel compiler and getting it to decompile it to an older version of js can be helpful, [try this](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA3jANiAhgEwJZgOYBoYBOIArlAKYBc8MADitmQHIoC2ZMAvDAORpkBmKYoijcYAX07xJkrlAAWGCADoaRGhADcQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.3&externalPlugins=)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let props = {

    loading: 'Loading value goes here',
    route : {
        pageName: 'pagename value goes here'
    }
}
```

without de-structuring

```
const loading = props.loading;
const route = props.route.pageName || 'default';
```

with de-structuring

```
const { loading, route: { pageName = 'default' } = {} } = props;
```

we define distinct variables left-hand side of the assignment to define what values to unpack from the sourced variable.

`loading` and `pageName` are variables

`props` is sourced variable

we have just unpack the `props` object properties  by give the properties name to left-hand assignment.

we can also unpack nested object as you can see route is nested object in `props`

so in  de-structuring we will unpack the object properties

here we give `pageName` default value if it is `undefined`

For more info [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: your example without de-structuring will not work if `route` is not defined, you have missed this part `= {}` which is equivalent to: `props.route = props.route || {};` then you can get the `pageName` : `const pageName = props.route.pageName || 'default';`

Answer (score 0):

From props you are getting 2 parameters loading & pageName. If pageName has no value (undefined) it will get the default string value "default".

you need to write "route" too to check nested key (pageName) if there is no route key in this.props you provide default value (empty object)

Answer (score 0):

```
const { loading, route: { pageName = 'default' } = {} } = this.props;
```

I would write it as below for you to grasp easily :

```
const
    {
      loading,
      route: {
               pageName = 'default'
             }
    }

this.props is like so :
    {
      loading,
      route: {
               pageName
             }
    }
```

Now this would just map the properties exactly no matter how deep. So whatever is in this.props.loading will go into loading counterpart in const. Whatever is in the `this.props.route.pageName` will go into `route.pageName` in the const. If `pageName` is empty or undefined in the props then 'default' value will be there. It is just like the default value is provided for an argument of a function if nothing is provided for that in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest form it will compile to

```
const loading = this.props.loading ;
let pageName ;
let route ;
if(this.props.route){
  route = this.props.route ;
  if(this.props.route. pageName){
     pageName = this.props.route. pageName ;
  } else {
    pageName = 'default' ;
  }
} else{
 route = {};
}
```